# XPATH- I have a list of images. I want to use those to search and extract text located in the following <p>

Tags: python, html, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have a list of image names from scraping images from a website like:

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jph
```

I want to associate those images with the text in the following `<p>` in the html below.  So in the example below I want to associate image1.jpg and image2.jpg with "The Federal Department of Fish"

How could I use xpath (or something else) to do that?

```
<td> 
    <p align = "center">
        <a href "http://imagessite.gov" target = "_blank">
            <img src = "image1.jpg" width = "100" height = "60" alt = "description">
            <img src = "image2.jpg" width = "100" height = "60" alt = "a purple ant">
        </a>
    </p>
    <p align = "center">
        <img src = "globe.gif">
        <a href = "http://imagesite.gov" target = "blank"> The Federal Department of Fish</a>
    </p>
</td>
```

Comment: How did you try to solve the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "associate"?

Comment: @mzjn Refer to the third part of my post *bolded text*, as I think that's what he needs... he can then iterate through keys or values.. or both...

Answer (score 0):

```
a ='''<td> 
    <p align = "center">
        <a href "http://imagessite.gov" target = "_blank">
            <img src = "image1.jpg" width = "100" height = "60" alt = "description">
            <img src = "image2.jpg" width = "100" height = "60" alt = "a purple ant">
        </a>
    </p>
    <p align = "center">
        <img src = "globe.gif">
        <a href = "http://imagesite.gov" target = "blank"> The Federal Department of Fish</a>
    </p>
</td>'''
```

I've stored the html you have gave us and the rest of the code should be looking something like this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'lxml')
table = soup.findAll('img') #finds all img tags 

for tag in table: # We loop through the mentioned
    if tag['src'].endswith('.jpg'): # this will check if the value from src ends with .jpg 
        print(tag['src'])
```

as for the association part, I think you mean something like this. I'll add a portion after. **The question that the user is asking ,*I think* ,is if we, for example, look up image1.jpg we want the text 'The Federal Department of Fish' associated/related to it.**

I guess that would be a ***dict*** or something. However, I tried doing it with for example `tag.parent.parent.next_sibling` it doesn't work I'll look into it 
later and edit and add.